# ResponseEntity does not accept return type "byte[]" but "ResponseEntity"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to send data from one server to another one via REST endpoint:

Server B starts this request:

```
String resource = "http://...";
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.getForObject(resource, byte[].class, customerID);
```

Server A receives the request and returns the file:

```
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> resp = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(myByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), HttpStatus.OK);
    return resp;
```

But I get an error at the .getForObject line:

```
Required Type: ResponseEntity[]
Provided: byte[]
```

So obviously I would have to change the statement to:

```
byte[] response = restTemplate.getForObject(resource, byte[].class, customerID);
```

or to

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.getForObject(resource, ResponseEntity.class, customerID);
```

Then the error is gone but I lose the HttpStatus.Ok message at the response? What would be the proper solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `getForObject` method does not provide access to response metadata like headers and the status code. If you have to access this data, then use [`RestTemplate#getForEntity(url, responseType, uriVariables)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-)

The `RestTemplate#getForEntity` returns a wrapper `ResponseEntity<T>` so you can read the response metadata and also read the body through the `getBody()` method.

```java
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(resource, byte[].class, customerID);
if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
    byte[] responseContent = response.getBody();
    // ...
} else {
    // this is not very useful because for error codes (4xx and 5xx) the RestTemplate throws an Exception
}
```

Comment: Ah that did it for me, thanks!